# DynamoDB unanswered update request

Tags: javascript, api, express, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I’m trying to perform an update in a DynamoDB table but for some reason, despite having written the query (params) correctly, I get an empty object as a result.

The project is built in Express with an MVVM design pattern similar to the one normally used in Sprint.

It's important to mention that whenever I execute the update via "controller - service - repository" in a single state, not an array, it works.  On the other hand, when I execute the process via "controller - service - service - repository" the execution fails.  I'm guessing it's a problem with synchronization but I'm not really sure where exactly.

**Directory path**:

```
├───Handler.js
│   ├───Controller
│        ├───exampleController.js
│   └───Service
│        ├───exampleService.js
│        ├───singleUpdateService.js
│   └───Repository
│        ├───exampleRepository.js
```

**Postman use case**:

```
{
    "id": "21313",
    "text": "text string",
    "arrayData": [true]
}
```

**Handler.js code sample**:

```
...
app.use('/api/example', exampleController);
...
```

**exampleController.js code sample**:

```
...router and express import

router.post('/example', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(await exampleService.updateExample(req));
});
..
```

**exampleService.js code sample**:

This function receives an array of boolean states and these states have to be inserted in the database consuming the function of another service layer.

controller - service - service - repository

```
...
exports.updateExample = (req) => {
    const { id, text, arrayData } = JSON.parse(req.body.toString('utf8'))

    //the singleState value is taken from arrayData using a .map
    // mapping function is commented as the values are explicitly passed as arguments
    //...arrayData.map( singleState =>{  
       return singleUpdateService.singleUpdateExample(id, text, singleState); //singleState = arrayData[0] 
    //...});
};
...
```

**singleUpdateService.js code sample**:

```
...
exports.singleUpdateExample= (id, text, state) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'table',
        Key: {
            'id': { 'S': id },
            'text': text
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'set state = :state',
        ConditionExpression: 'text = :text',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':state': state,
            ':text': text
        },
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };
    return exampleRepository.update(params);
}
...
```

**exampleRepository.js code sample**:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const docClientUpd = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.update = (params) => {
    return docClientUpd.update(params, async (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            return err;
        return result;
    }).promise();
}
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Do you get an error that can be posted as well?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get any error as a response; I only get an empty object {}.